# How to store non-reactive data in Vuex?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vuex

I have data, that loaded on page once before VueJS-application init, and this data will not change for all time while html-page will not reload (classic CGI application, not SPA). Data example:

```
const nonReactiveObjectWithSomeNestedData = {
  a: 'a',
  b: {
    bb: 'bb',
    cc: { ccc: 'ccc' },
    dd: ['dd1', 'dd2']
  }
}
```

I am using this data in a few vue-components. It would be handy to store this data in Vuex namespaced module and to use Vuex-getters for wrapping same functionality for different vue-components. Is there any way to store this data not inside vuex `state` (reactivity not needed) but with ability to access from vuex-module's getter?

**PS.** Currently I am using storing non-reactive data [inside vue-instance](https://github.com/vuejs/vue/issues/1988#issuecomment-163013818) method, but now it is not enough, I need more global access to data (from two independent root-components).

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Freeze the object before adding it to the store:

```
Object.freeze(nonReactiveObjectWithSomeNestedData )
```

Vue won't make frozen objects reactive.

**Note:** you should freeze object before it comes into Vuex mutation/action:

```
this.$store.dispatch('moduleName/setNonReactiveObject', 
    Object.freeze(nonReactiveObjectWithSomeNestedData));
```

Inside mutation function the payload-parameter will be already reactive.

Comment: And what if we need to change that object later but still don't want the reactivity?

Comment: 1. make a copy `const copy = { ..original }`, 2. change that copy, 3. freeze the copy, 4. replace original in store with the copy.

Comment: Right now I'm using vuex 3.0.1 and the payload-parameter is not "already reactive" inside action and mutation functions (but afterwards of course).

Answer (score 6):

One can also add a property `_isVue` to the object to avoid making it reactive.

```
commit('setNonReactiveObject', Object.assign(data, { _isVue: true })
```

This approach can be useful to make data non-reactive when there's no way to control how the data is stored in the store. For example when store data is completely replaced client-side to "hydrate" a server-side rendered website (e.g. Nuxt).

This is undocumented and might break in the future.
At least the [source code](https://github.com/vuejs/vue/blob/0d2e9c46f16e9ec5bd0f3eebd2aa31c7f7493856/src/core/instance/init.js#L30) has a comment indicating that this property is used for this internally. And [here](https://github.com/vuejs/vue/blob/0b31647c41b0c916d40b962723b1de06672d0e01/src/core/observer/index.js#L122) is where the property is checked before *observing* the object.

Answer (score 2):

I was able to remove the "reactiveness" by doing something like this

```
// create new variable and remove reactiveness, does a deep clone
var someNewNonReactiveVar = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(someReactiveVar));
```

Answer (score 0):

In mutation file you can deep clone the payload that you don't want to be reactive

```
import _ from 'lodash';

    [mutationTypes.SET_INITIAL_STATE](state, payload) {
    // In order to make sure that this property is non-reactive deep clone it
    state.initialState = _.cloneDeep(payload)
}
```

This way the initialState or whatever property you're adding to the state, won't be reactive.