# Share constants between Vue components

Tags: vue.js, vue-component

I have a collection of static data that I want to access in some of my Vue components. Example:

```js
COLORS = Object.freeze({
    RED: 1,
    GREEN: 2,
    BLUE: 3,
})
FLAVOURS = Object.freeze({
    VANILLA: 'vanilla',
    CHOCOLATE: 'chocolate',
})
```

- I'm working with single file components.
- I want to access those constants both in component template and in JS code (i.e. in `data()`).
- I don't want them to be reactive.
- If possible, I want them to be instantiated only once (not copying each constant into each component instance).
- I don't currently use Vuex, but I'll consider it if it leads to more elegant solution.

I tried to solve my problem using `mixin`:

```js
// ColorMixin.js
export const COLORS = Object.freeze({
    RED: 1,
    GREEN: 2,
})

export const ColorMixin = {
    created() {
        this.COLORS = COLORS
    }
}
```

Then, in my component I have to use that `mixin` and also the constants:

```js
<template>
    <input name="red" :value="COLORS.RED" />
    <input name="green" :value="COLORS.GREEN" />
</template>
<script>
    import {COLORS, ColorMixin} from './ColorMixin.js'
    export default {
        mixins: [ColorMixin],
        data() {
            return {
                default_color: COLORS.RED,
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

This works, but it seems kind of repetitive. Is there a more elegant solution for my problem?

Answer (score 2):

How about just using a [global mixin](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/mixins.html#Global-Mixin) ?

```
// import your constants
Vue.mixin({
  created: function () {
    this.COLORS = COLORS;
  }
})
```

Comment: I know about global mixins, but that's not what I'm aiming for. As I wrote, I don't want to copy each constant into each component instance. There are many components that does not need to have these constants available.

Answer (score 0):

You do not just import the exported var from your `Color.js` file into correct SFC ?

```
COLORS = Object.freeze({
  RED: 1,
  GREEN: 2,
  BLUE: 3,
});
FLAVOURS = Object.freeze({
  VANILLA: 'vanilla',
  CHOCOLATE: 'chocolate',
});

export {COLORS, FLAVOURS};
```

and then in your SFC

```
<template>
  <input name="red" :value="default_color" />
</template>

<script>
  import {COLORS, FLAVOURS} from './Color.js';

  export default {
    data() {
      return {
        default_color: COLORS.RED,
        default_flavour: FLAVOURS.CHOCOLATE,
      }
    }
  }
</script>
```

Or just create a Vuex store to save this datas and use it directly from each SFC

Comment: I could do that, but the repetitiveness is even greater (I'd have to redefine all the constants I want to use in templates again in the data). I expanded the template in the question to also contain green color.

Comment: Is there a way to use a Vuex store for saving not-reactive data? edit: It seems there is (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47452401/how-to-store-non-reactive-data-in-vuex). I'll try that.

Comment: So it seems that Vuex is not the answer, because it requires all constants to be defined as computed properties. Even with `mapState` helper, this is still very much repetitive.